# google-app-engine 1.9.19 deploy failure

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When trying to deploy using the new Python GoogleAppEngine-1.9.19 in the form of the GAE launcher on Windows 7, I'm not asked to authenticate. Instead, I get a page for accepting GAE management, and then I'm running locally. Moreover, clicking the close box on the launcher does nothing and I have to kill it externally.
I don't understand the error messages or what to do. I don't have a file named old_run.py. I uninstalled 1.9.19 and reinstalled 1.9.18, and deploy works as always. Is 1.9.19 broken?

```
2015-04-15 11:27:47 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--oauth2', 'update', 'M:\\HP_Cdrive\\workspace\\glowscript']"
11:27 AM Application: glowscript; version: 1
11:27 AM Host: appengine.google.com
11:27 AM 
Starting update of app: glowscript, version: 1
11:27 AM Getting current resource limits.
2015-04-15 11:27:50,838 WARNING old_run.py:88 This function, oauth2client.tools.run(), and the use of the gflags library are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the library. 
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fappengine.admin+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&response_type=code&client_id=550516889912.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run
this application with the command-line parameter 

  --noauth_local_webserver
```

Comment: I can't get 1.9.19 to update in Elcipse IDE either

Comment: We've switched over the oauth2 authentication in the new Windows Launcher. Please click "Accept" when prompted for oauth permission in the browser, and the app should be deployed correctly.

Comment: As I said, after clicking "Accept" I was dumped onto my localhost 8080 page. No deployment occurred. I had to retreat to 1.9.18 in order to deploy.

Comment: After clicking "accept", you should see a message saying that the authentication is complete. If you then go back to the launcher's console, you should see that the deployment continues.

Comment: Yes, that is of course what one would expect, but I repeat that this is not what happened. I see that Les Vogel (see below) suspects that 1.19.19 is buggy. I have had to retreat to 1.9.18.

Comment: Do you get the solution, I've same problem in my system.

Answer (score 14):

It's an issue with Google App Engine SDK, which doesn't allow the user authentication process to be completed, if local server is running.

Step 1. Stop the local server.

Step 2. Click on 'Deploy'

Step 3. You should get a message `"The authentication flow has completed."`

Step 4. Close the Window.

Step 5. Deploy again using Google App Engine. You should receive a message `You 
can close this window now.`

Answer (score 3):

you just have to shut down the server I use the google app engine luncher run and stop then deploy

Comment: You might add the method and command how to shut down (and restart?) the server.

Comment: Thanks! First stopping the application run with the Google App Engine Launcher solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about that - the tooling is in the process of changing.  The docs should be updated shortly.

Try `gcloud preview app deploy path-to/your.yaml --project myProjectID`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the answer, because I've been depending on being able to click "Deploy" in the GAE Launcher and have avoided having to learn how to execute appropriate commands in a Windows command prompt. I sure hope you're not telling me that the "Deploy" button is no longer going to work in the Launcher....?

Comment: No - sorry -  I misread your question -- It's possible you've run into a bug in 1.9.19 regarding how auth works.  Probably best to stay on 1.9.18 for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy successfully in 1.9.19 by using command line.

```
appcfg.py update myapp/
```

Use an [application-specific password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) instead of your regular account password.

In any case, you'll get a message that:

> now the recommended way to log in is using OAuth2. See
>   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_
>   Password-less_login_with_OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with the **redirection** to `localhost:8085`, you can try to use `wget` from the server you're trying to authenticate, something like:

```
wget http://localhost:8085/?code=4/SOMELONGKEY#
```

After this you should be logged.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was not version parameter in app.yaml file. When I add the parameter it has worked.

```
application: myappname
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
version: 1
```