# How to get an old Google App Engine SDK version

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having exactly the same problem like this one: [google-app-engine 1.9.19 deploy failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657557/google-app-engine-1-9-19-deploy-failure)

Please, someone can explain me how to get an older version of GAE's SDKs?
In this particular case I need the version 1.9.18 for Python.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be an actual question, but a request. I'd delete it after solving the issue. You can just play around with the download url from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads), by changing to the version you need

Comment: There is no option to change the version. If you go to "Previous SDKs" the version 1.9.18 is not there.

Comment: you have to change it manually... i.e if you want the Python SDK for linux, take https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.19.zip and replace 19 with 18 to get https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.18.zip

Comment: if you reformulate the question to ask how to get an old version of the GAE SDK, I could create an answer and make this useful for someone in the future ;)

Comment: Let's not do that, since asking to for software libraries and other off-site resources (such as appengine SDK) is off-topic for SO :-)

Comment: I'm ok with deleting the question @TimCastelijns... but if the edit gets accepted, is more generic on how to get the version, and not a handout of the version itself

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's generic or not, the purpose of the question remains the same, and is still off-topic (although I approved your edit anyway)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most versions should be available in the [Deprecated page](https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks/deprecated)

If the particular version you are trying to get is not there, you could always play around with the Download URLs, to get the one you need.

For example:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.19.zip
```

Can be modified to:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/appengine-sdks/featured/google_appengine_1.9.18.zip
```

Comment: Basically you can browse through them from: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/appengine-sdks downwards