# Can't deploy python app to the cloud with googe app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a simple hello world app that I can run locally without any problem. Clicking on browse in Google App Engine on Windows shows the app on the address:

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

But when I click on deploy, instead of showing on `myappid.appscpot.com`, the app displays on `http://localhost:8080/?code=4/alotofrandomletters#`

The deployment to google log shows:

```
2015-07-12 18:47:52 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--oauth2_credential_file=C:\\Users\\myname/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens', 'update', u'C:\\Users\\myname\\Dropbox\\myapp\\myapp']"
06:47 PM Application: myapp; version: 1
06:47 PM Host: appengine.google.com
06:47 PM 
Starting update of app: myapp, version: 1
06:47 PM Getting current resource limits.
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?alotoflettersandnumbers.apps.googleusercontent.com&access_type=offline

If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
application with the command-line parameter 

  --noauth_local_webserver
```

After I click on deploy google asks me for rights in the browser and I grant them. Yet the app runs locally. Why does it not show on `myappid.appscpot.com`?

Comment: Supposing that you have indeed correctly followed that OAuth flow to identify yourself as an authorized user to deploy your application, you seem to be mispelling "myappid.appscpot.com". It should be "myappid.appspot.com", without that 'c' letter in the middle

Comment: Deploying doesn't automatically stop the local server, if it was running it will continue running and serving the app on localhost. You need to specifically try to open the site on `appspot.com` (BTW, please check your url, I see you have the same typo twice in the question: it's `appspot`, not `appscpot`). Also - is the deployment log you pasted complete? At least on linux it clearly indicates all uploading steps, including uploaded stats, clear indication that the uploaded completed and checks that the app is serving.

Comment: if I enter http://myprojectid.appspot.com/ into the browser, I get the following: Error: Not Found. The requested URL / was not found on this server. Same if I enter http://myprojectid.appspot.com:8080/

Comment: Please show your `app.yaml` .

Comment: My app stated working on appspot. Maybe Google just needed a few hours to setup my app engine account

Answer (score 0):

*It's an issue with Google App Engine SDK, which doesn't allow the user authentication process to be completed, if local server is running.*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32111611/4853690

thanks Ashwani Agarwal!!